# Python does't search for libraries in the right path (windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, path, version

I have 2 installations of Python on my windows computer:

Python3.6.5 with Anaconda:

```
C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
```

Python3.8.5 with WinPython:

```
C:\Users\Pedro\Documents\Softwares\Winpython.385\python-3.8.5.amd64\python.exe
```

I can well double click on the WinPython python.exe. It works well.

When I double click on the Anaconda python.exe, it crashes.

```
.\python.exe : Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\Documents\Softwares\Winpython.385\python-3.8.5.amd64\Lib\abc.py", line 64, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_abc'
```

Why Anaconda python is looking for modules in Winpython folder ?

WinPython folder is not in the env path of my shell.

If I delete Winpython folder, Anaconda python.exe works well.

Comment: different python versions hold different files and can't import from one another, so I would assume in this case this file really doesn't exist.
Perhaps you can reinstall python3.8 on conda if your current installation is corrupted.
Also - make sure you install the right version for your chip - here you have an amd64 build

Comment: As I wrote "If I delete Winpython folder, Anaconda python.exe works well." Anaconda Python is - i don't know why - looking for libs in a totally different folder before checking for libs in its own folder

Comment: I think that this is linked with Window$, MyDocuments is maybe a priority folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a windows bug.

Moving the folder of python3.8.5 elsewhere solved my issue.